# How do I create a Routed Event in Silverlight 2?

Tags: silverlight, events

Anyone know how to create a routed event in Silverlight 2?  In WPF, the code would be like  below. However, there’s no EventManager in Silverlight.

```
    public static readonly RoutedEvent ShowVideoEvent =
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ShowVideo", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(NavBar));

    public event RoutedEventHandler ShowVideo
    {
        add { AddHandler(ShowVideoEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(ShowVideoEvent, value); }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for the time being, there [doesn't seem to be a way](http://blogs.telerik.com/HristoHristov/Posts/08-07-23/Routed_Events_in_Silverlight_2.aspx) to create your own. That post was however for Beta2, looking at the [document for Beta2->RC0 breaking changes](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/F/E/6FE1F43D-9D0C-4346-AD08-602DF9BCB3CF/BreakingChangesBetweenBeta2andRelease.doc), there doesn't seem to be any mention of anything. But then I guess it could be no breaking change, we can always hope eh ;)

There are a number of [events which are routed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189018(VS.95).aspx#bubbled) but again I'm not sure this documentation has been updated for RC0.